# node.js timeout restarts api call

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sails.js, fetch

**Platform:**

I have an api in [sails.js](https://sailsjs.com/) and a frontend in [react](https://reactjs.org/). The calls between front and back end are being made with [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

**More information:**

In the course of some api endpoints I have to execute an external file, at this point I am using the [execfile()](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback) function of [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/), and I have to wait for it to be executed to respond to the frontend.

**What is the problem?**

If the file is executed in a short time, for example less than 1 minute everything runs well and the behavior occurs as expected on both sides, but if (in this case) the file takes more than 1 minute to execute, there is something to trigger a second call to api *(I do not know where this is being called, but I tested the same endpoint with [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) and I did not have this problem so I suspect the react / fetch-api)* and the api call with the same data from the first call is redone. This causes the file to run twice.

Something that is even stranger is that if you have the DevTools Network inspector turned on this second call does not appear, but nothing in the documentation of sailjs points to this behavior.

**Example of an endpoint in sails.js:**

```
/**
 * FooController
 */
const execFile = require("child_process").execFile;
module.exports = {
  foo: async (req, res) => {
    let result = await module.exports._executeScript(req.body).catch(() => {
      res.status(500).json({ error: "something has occurred" });
    });
    res.json(result);
  },
  _executeScript: body => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let args = [process.cwd() + "/scripts/" + "myExternalFile.js", body];
      let elem = await module.exports
        ._execScript(args)
        .catch(err => reject(err));
      resolve(elem);
    });
  },
  _execScript: args => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        execFile("node", args, { timeout: 150000 }, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
          if (error || (stderr != null && stderr !== "")) {
            console.error(error);
          } else {
            console.log(stdout);
          }
          let output = { stdout: stdout, stderr: stderr };
          resolve(output);
        });
      } catch (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
    });
  }
};
```

**Example of component react with fetch call:**

```
import React from "react";
import { notification } from "antd";
import "./../App.css";
import Oauth from "./../helper/Oauth";
import Config from "./../config.json";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      syncInAction: false,
      data: null
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.handleSync();
  }
  async handleSync() {
    let response = await fetch(Config.apiLink + "/foo/foo", {
      method: "POST",
      mode: "cors",
      headers: {
        Authorization: Oauth.isLoggedIn(),
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(this.state.myData)
    }).catch(err => {
      notification.error({
        key: "catch-ApiFail",
        message: "Erro"
      });
    });

    let json = await response.json();
    this.setState({
      syncInAction: false,
      data: json
    });
  }
  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.data}</div>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

**What is my expected goal / behavior:**

It does not matter if the call takes 1 minute or 10 hours, the file can only be called once and when it finishes, then yes, it can return to the frontend.

*Note that the examples do not have the original code and have not been tested. Is a simplified version of the code to explain the behavior*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem, apparently [nodejs has a default timing of 2 minutes](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/http.html#http_server_settimeout_msecs_callback) on the server, and can be rewritten to miss this timout or increase it.
This was just adding a line of code at the beginning of the foo() endpoint and the problem was solved.

The behavior of redoing the call is that it is not documented, and it is strange not to have this behavior when using the postman, but here is the solution for whoever needs it.

**Final result:**

```
foo: async (req, res) => {
  req.setTimeout(0);
  let result = await module.exports._executeScript(req.body).catch(() => {
    res.status(500).json({ error: "something has occurred" });
  });
  res.json(result);
};
```